# SQL - Nested Sub-Queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists, sql-view

Using postgresql, I have to create a view called 'no_cat_customers' that returns the first name, last name of any customer who has not been shipped any edition of the book named 'The Cat in the Hat'. This should be done using universal quantification. The error I'm getting is - "ERROR: EXCEPT types integer and text cannot be matched" in reference to line 7 (`EXCEPT (SELECT shipments.isbn`).

```
CREATE VIEW no_cat_customers(customer_first_name, customer_last_name)
AS SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT c_id
              FROM shipments
              WHERE customers.c_id = shipments.c_id 
              EXCEPT (SELECT shipments.isbn
                      FROM books, editions, shipments
                      WHERE books.book_id = editions.book_id AND
                        editions.isbn = shipments.isbn AND
                        title LIKE '%The Cat in the Hat%'));
```

I understand that this is hard to ask considering you don't have the database I'm using, but any help with this would be very much appreciated!

EDIT: I should add that there is two editions of 'The Cat in the Hat' in the database, both with different isbn's. So that has to be taken into account.

Comment: Must *any other* shipments->items  have been delivered to these customers?

Comment: @wildplasser nope, they just have to be on the customer list and not received the cat in the hat

Comment: In that case you can do with only `select * from customers c where not exists(select * from shipments s join books ON .. JOIN editions e ON ... WHERE c.cid = s.cid and b.title LIKE '%cat%' );` -->> you want ALL customers who DID NOT order that particular book"

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks heaps, but I've been told I must use a query that contains 'multiple' other subqueries but this only contains one

Comment: @Brittany task limitations are pretty amazing in this way. Add another select * layer on top of it and there you go, multiple subqueries :-).

Comment: @ConsiderMe so true. Although I'm struggling to get wildplasser's solution working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of mixing it with real conditions in where clause. I believe that this should work:

```
CREATE VIEW no_cat_customers(customer_first_name, customer_last_name) AS 
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM shipments s
  JOIN editions e ON s.isbn = e.isbn
  JOIN books b ON b.book_id = e.book_id
  WHERE b.title ILIKE '%The Cat in the Hat%'
  AND c.c_id = s.c_id
  )
```

If you have datatype errors, cast your columns to appropriate types before comparing them.

Comment: I did have to adjust to b.title = '%The Cat in the Hat%'. But unfortunately this just returned the whole customer list

Comment: Add ILIKE instead of =